# how do I change #autoenable=false to true?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

After I enter `sudoedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf` I am still not able to use my bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04

```
# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
#AutoEnable=false











^G Get Help  ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut Text  ^J Justify   ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^R Read File ^\ Replace   ^U Uncut Text^T To Spell  ^_ Go To Line
```

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your bluetooth issue, but to change it to true, remove `#` from the start of the line and change `false` to `true`. You can use `sudo sed -i 's/#AutoEnable=false/AutoEnable=true/' /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Comment: no still it's same even after i used your above command# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
#AutoEnable=false

Comment: This is my actual problem. please see it if you can help.                                                                        http://askubuntu.com/questions/855678/im-not-being-able-to-use-bluetooth-in-my-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

1. enter  `sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
2. erase `false` and enter `true`
3. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> at the same time to exit. (In `nano`, `^` at the bottom menu means to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.)
4. <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Comment: please format code, filepaths and make your steps a numbered list for better readability